# How to access Windows 7 partitions like D:/ and E:/?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my PC. I cannot access the contents of my hard disk which contain Windows old files.

Comment: is it giving an error? Or you don't know how to mount the drive?

Comment: The drive gets mounted automatically, unless it is protected and/or in an unknown format.
@Rahul_Jha : Try to go to your `/media` Folder and check for your drive there.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu, from within Windows, side-by-side with Windows or erase the disk with Windows and install Ubuntu all by itself? If the later, then I am afraid all the partitions on the disk is gone. Please update the question with the type of your installation and search [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com) for similar questions.

Comment: Question is too vague to be answerable.